# Proof that infinite bisections of an interval leads to a unique point in the intersection.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I want to proof that if we have a sequence of closed intervals $\{ I_n \} $ such that $I_{n+1}$ is the bisection of $I_{n}$, then there is a unique point $x\in\bigcap I_n$  without using the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, since that is exactly what I am trying to prove.

Since $I_{n+1}\subset I_n$ for all $n$, by the nested interval property there exists at least one point $x\in\bigcap I_n$. Now, if $I_1=[a,b]$ and $I_n=[a_n,b_n]$, then $$\ell(I_n)=\frac{b-a}{2^{n-1}}$$ and therefore for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $N>0$ such that $|b_n-a_n|<\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N$, which means that the terms of $\{a_n \}$ and $\{b_n\}$ are getting closer. I know I have to prove that $\sup\{a_n\}=\inf\{b_n\}$ but I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I=\bigcap I_n$. Assume exsits more than one point in $I$, then we can pick a point $y$, and $y\neq x$, $y\in I$. Define the distance $d=|x-y|$, so $d>0$ is some fixed number.

But there exists some $N$, such that $\ell(I_n)<\frac{d}2, \forall n\ge N$. Note that $x,y\in I_n$, which means $|x-y|\le \ell(I_n) $ so you get $$d=|x-y|\le \ell(I_n)<\frac{d}2$$

Contradictions.

Answer (score 1):

For a direct proof, suppose that $x$ and $y$ belong to $I:=\bigcap I_n$. Then for every $n$ we have $x\in I_n$ and $y\in I_n$, so $$|x-y|\le \ell(I_n)\tag1$$ for every $n$. Since RHS of (1) tends to zero as $n\to\infty$, conclude $|x-y|=0$ and $x=y$.